# svg animateTransform trigger multiple animations simultaneously

Tags: svg, svg-animate

In the following example I need all animations to be executed  simultaneously. But works only last one.

```
<g>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
    type="rotate" values="2 100 100; -1 100 100; 1 100 100; -0.5 100 100 0.5 100 100" begin="indefinite" dur="0.35s" fill="freeze" />

    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                      type="scale" values="1; 1.2; 1" begin="indefinite" dur="0.35s" fill="freeze" />

    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                      type="translate" values="0 0; -100 -100; 0; 0" begin="indefinite" dur="0.35s" fill="freeze" />

    <image x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"  xlink:href="<?php  echo $cck->getValue('project_icon'); ?>" />
</g>
```

Action has been triggered by js:

```
var animations = $( $this ).find( 'animateTransform' );
animations[0].beginElement();
animations[1].beginElement();
animations[2].beginElement();
```

Comment: Add the attribute animate="sum" to all your animateTransforms.  I put this as the answer but some power-hungry monitor deleted it.

Answer (score 18):

You have few errors in your script:

> begin="indefinite"

should be:

> repeatCount="indefinite"

in the **rotation** values you forgot to separate the last **value** with semicolon and you have an extra semicolon in **translate** section.

In order to execute few transformations you need to sum the results by adding (no need to add this to first transformation)

> additive="sum"

So your code should look like:

```
<g>
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate" values="2 100 100;-1 100 100;1 100 100;-0.5 100 100;0.5 100 100" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="0.35s" fill="freeze" />

   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                      type="scale" values="1;1.2;1" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="0.35s" fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>

   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                      type="translate" values="0 0;-100 -100;0 0" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="0.35s" fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>

   <image x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"  xlink:href="<?php  echo $cck->getValue('project_icon'); ?>" />
</g>
```

BTW rotating your image at 0.5 degrees is unnoticeable so why bother?!

here you can read more about it:
[SVG-SMIL animation tutorial](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/SVG-SMIL_animation_tutorial)